# Rebol library access

Tags: rebol

Isn't library access free in R2? I'm running 2.7.8.4.2 on Ubuntu and R2 complains when I try to load [Dobeash's sqlite.r](http://www.dobeash.com/sqlite.html), I see this message:

```
** Script Error: Feature not available in this REBOL  
** Where: main  
** Near: version: to tuple! do make
```

The same code seems to work fine in R2 View!

Answer (score 4):

The /Library component is only available in the for-free REBOL/View, not in the for-free REBOL/Core.

Comment: Same for odbc access, it is only available for View not for Core.